# let $\Psi (n,z)=\sum_{\substack{d|n \\ p|d \Rightarrow p>z}}{1\over d}$，I want to find a z as small as possible related to n so that $\Psi (n,z)=O(1)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, combinations, analytic-number-theory

let $\Psi (n,z)=\sum\limits_{\substack{d|n \\ p|d \Rightarrow p>z}}{1\over d}$，I want to find a "z" as small as possible related to n so that $\Psi (n,z)=O(1)$ or $\Psi (n,z)=o(1)$

the below is what I have done:

$$
\begin{aligned} \Psi(n,z) &=\sum\limits_{\substack{d|n \\ p|d \Rightarrow p>z}} {1\over d} \\  &=\prod\limits_{\substack{p^k ||n \\ p>z}}  (1+{1\over p}+\dots+{1\over p^k})   \;\;\;(Euler \;product\; formula )\\  & \le  \prod\limits_{\substack{p |n \\ p>z}}  (1+ {1\over p-1}) \;\;\;(summation \;formula \;of\;geometric\;series ) \end{aligned}
$$

Then，take nature logarithm.

We get,
$$
    \begin{aligned}  \log\Psi(n,z)  &=\sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ p>z}}  \log (1+{1\over p-1})  \;\;\; \\ &\le  \sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ p>z}}  {1\over p-1}  \;\;\;(a \;inequality \;about\; logarithm)\\ &\le   \sum\limits_{\substack{p|n }}  {1\over z-1}  \\ &\le {1 \over z-1} \log n \end{aligned}
$$

so we get $ \begin{aligned}  \log\Psi(n,z)   &\le {1 \over z-1} \log n \end{aligned}$.

$\begin{aligned}  \Psi(n,z)   &\le e^{ {1 \over z-1} \log n} \end{aligned}$

If we let $z=\log n +1$,
then we have :

$\begin{aligned}  \Psi(n,z)   &\le e^{ {1 \over z-1} \log n}=e=O(1) \end{aligned}$

so, we get a "z" related to n ,$z=\log n +1$ so  that $ \begin{aligned}  \Psi(n,z)   =O(1) \end{aligned}$

But I feel my result seems too weak, is there any stronger result?

The stronger the better.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Your result is sufficient for many applications in sieve estimates

Comment: I seems get a stronger result.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking for a period of time, I find it seems not particularly difficult to make stronger results.

It perhaps needs one or two small tricks .

Let's review the previous derivation steps

$
    \begin{aligned}  \log\Psi(n,z)  &=\sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ p>z}}  \log (1+{1\over p-1})  \;\;\; \\ &\le  \sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ p>z}}  {1\over p-1}  \;\;\;\\ &\le   \sum\limits_{\substack{p|n }}  {1\over z-1}  \\ &\le {1 \over z-1} \log n \end{aligned}
$

Let's focus on $\begin{aligned} \sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ p>z}}  {1\over p-1}  \end{aligned}$ and split it .

we have ,

$\begin{aligned} \sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ p>z}}  {1\over p-1} = \underbrace{\sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ z < p < \log n +1}}  {1\over p-1} }_{S_1} +\underbrace{ \sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ \log n +1 \le p }}  {1\over p-1} }_{S_2} \end{aligned}$

### The calculation of $S_2$

Now consider the number of different prime factors in n that are greater than or equal to $ \log ⁡ n + 1$, and record this number as a

We have ,

$\begin{aligned} \left( \log n+1 \right)^a\le \prod_{1\le r \le a} p_r \le n \end{aligned}$ ,where $p_r,1\le r \le a$,is the prime factor of n that  greater than or equal to $ \log ⁡ n + 1$

So we get ,
$\begin {aligned} \sum_{ \substack {p|n \\ \log n+1 \le p } } 1=a\le {\log n \over \log (\log n +1)} <  {\log n \over \log \log n }  \end {aligned}$

$\begin{aligned} S_2&={ \sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ \log n +1 \le p }}  {1\over p-1} }\\ &\le { \sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ \log n +1 \le p }}  {1\over \log n} } \\ &< {1\over \log n}  {  { \log n\over \log \log n} }  \;\;\;(\sum_{ \substack {p|n \\ \log n+1 \le p } } 1 <  {\log n \over \log \log n } used\; here )\\  &={1  \over \log \log n } \end{aligned}$

The calculation of $S_2$ here is basically the same as the derivation of the description of the question.

This splitting makes the range of z smaller ,So we just need to focus on the smaller range of z .

### The calculation of $S_1$

$\begin{aligned} S_1={\sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ z < p < \log n +1}}  {1\over p-1} } \le {\sum\limits_{\substack{ \\ z < p < \log n +1}}  {1\over p-1} } \end{aligned}$

Here, we can easily think of Mertens's second theorem.

**mertens's second theorem**
$
\sum_{p\le x}\frac1p=\log\log x+B_1+\mathcal O\left(1\over\log x\right) \tag1
$where $B_1=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\sum_{p\le x}\frac1p-\log\log x\right]$ is the mertens constant.

First, we make a difference between
$\begin{aligned} {\sum\limits_{\substack{ \\ z < p < \log n +1}}  {1\over p-1} } \end{aligned}$ and $\begin{aligned} {\sum\limits_{\substack{ \\ z < p < \log n +1}}  {1\over p} } \end{aligned}$

We have ,

$
\begin{aligned} {\sum\limits_{\substack{ \\ z < p < \log n +1}}  \left | {1\over p-1}  -{ 1 \over p}\right |}  &={\sum\limits_{\substack{ \\ z < p < \log n +1}}  \left | {1 \over p\,(p-1)}  \right |}  \\ & <{\sum\limits_{\substack{ \\ z < p < \log n +1}}  \left | {1 \over \,(p-1)^2}  \right |} \\ & <{\sum\limits_{\substack{ \\ z < t < \log n +1}}  \left | {1 \over \,(t-1)^2}  \right |}  \\ & \ll { 1 \over z} \end{aligned}
$

So

$
\begin{aligned} S_1\le{\sum\limits_{\substack{ \\ z < p < \log n +1}}  {1\over p-1} }=\begin{aligned} {\sum\limits_{\substack{ \\ z < p < \log n +1}}  {1\over p} }+ \mathcal O \left(\;{1 \over z} \;\right) \end{aligned}  \end{aligned}
$

Applying mertens second theorem (1) :

We have $\begin{aligned} S_1&\le {\sum\limits_{\substack{ \\ z < p < \log n +1}}  {1\over p} }+ \mathcal O \left(\;{1 \over z} \;\right)  \\ &=\log \log (\log n+1)-\log \log z+\mathcal O \left(\;{1 \over z} \;\right)  +\mathcal O \left(\;{1 \over \log n} \;\right)   \end{aligned}$

Consider that $z<\log n+1$,The $\mathcal O$ can be merged.

So we have $\begin{aligned} S_1 &\le\log \log  (\log n+1)-\log \log z+\mathcal O \left(\;{1 \over z} \;\right)  \\ &= \log  \left( {\log(\log n +1) \over \log z } \right) + \mathcal O \left(\;{1 \over z} \;\right)  \end{aligned}$

So far, we have completed the calculation of $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Reviewing the previous equation,

$\begin{aligned} \sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ p>z}}  {1\over p-1} = \underbrace{\sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ z < p < \log n +1}}  {1\over p-1} }_{S_1} +\underbrace{ \sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ \log n +1 \le p }}  {1\over p-1} }_{S_2} \end{aligned}$

Let's substitute $ \begin{aligned} S_1  &\le \log \left ( {\log(\log n +1) \over \log z } \right) + \mathcal O \left(\;{1 \over z} \;\right)  \end{aligned}$  and $\begin{aligned} S_2 < {1 \over \log \log n} \end{aligned}$ into the equation

We have

$
    \begin{aligned}  \log\Psi(n,z)   &\le  \sum\limits_{\substack{p|n \\ p>z}}  {1\over p-1}   \le \log \left ( {\log(\log n +1) \over \log z } \right) + \mathcal O \left(\;{1 \over z} \;\right) +\mathcal O \left(\;{1 \over \log \log n} \;\right)  \end{aligned}
$

This time we can get a smaller z .

For example ,

Let $z=\sqrt{\log n+1}$ ,this time we only observe $\begin{aligned} \log  \left( {\log(\log n +1) \over \log z } \right) \end{aligned}$

Then,

$\begin{aligned} \log \left ( {\log(\log n +1  \over \log z } \right)&= \log \left ( {\log(\log n +1) \over \log (\sqrt{\log n+1}) } \right)\\ &=\log \left ( {2\log(\log n +1) \over \log (\log n+1) } \right)\\ &=\log2 \end{aligned}$

$\log 2$ is a constant.

Through this derivation, in fact, we can always take a fixed number $\varepsilon$ greater than 0, let $z=\log ^\varepsilon n$, then $\Psi(n,z) =\mathcal O(1)$

Comment: Breaking the interval is a quite standard technique to estimate sums like this. I upvoted for this one.